# Best configuration for 1 SSD and 2 HDD's?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, ssd, sata, ahci

I'm going to be buying a sata 3 motherboard (Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3) and a new SSD (SATA 3) as my boot/programs disk.

In addition, I will be using my 2 old maxtor diamondback 10's (7200 - 300gb each) for data storage. One of which is SATA 1 and the other is SATA 2 (just to confuse things!)

I want the SSD to be fully independent and running in AHCI, for best performance.

I want the 2 HDD's to be in RAID (seperate from the SSD, to avoid any speed kill).

I am also running an IDE DVD drive in SATA, using a IDE-SATA converter. How will this fit into the configuration and will it work in AHCI mode?

How do i go about setting up this configuration? Or is there a better option?

The motherboard has 6 SATA ports, labelled 0-5. I've no idea what goes where or which ports are controlled by which controllers so some help here would be great!

Any answers here would be really appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: have a look at this: [SATA 1 & SATA 2 RAID](http://forums.hardwaresecrets.com/starting-raid-using/2052)

Answer (score 0):

i did make a video for installing to a SSD and a HDD - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sPGEwqoXA0
you should know that the GUI installer for ubuntu does not support raid
If your bios allows you to set 2 of the ports in raid and the rest in ahci it is possible, you probably would need a second sata controller for that
sata 1, 2, or 3 it does not matter as a hdd can't benefit from sata 3 as they are too slow, if your sata 2 drive is faster than your sata 1 drive you may not be able to raid them, raid works best with 2 of the same model
if you have 2 sata 1 posts i don't see that being a issue though
I would suggest RAID 1 for the HDDs (i think that is the one that does not loose data if 1 drive fails)
you may be able to do a software raid (remembered this as a i was typing this) that will only use some of your ports for raid, and have the bios set in ahci
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID
if someone can edit this to make it more readable please do, it is late here and i am sleepy
Edit: as for your IDE drives, i just looked at the motherboard, but i dont see a plug for a ribbon cable on the motherboard, unless you have a pci card for that (or ide to sata adapter) you are not going to be using them